# Why all , are not converted to decimals when importing in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using the following code to import the CSV file. It works well except for when it encounters a three digit number followed by a decimal. Below is my code and the result

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fft(x, Plot_ShareY=True): 
    dfs = pd.read_csv(x, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1,2), decimal=",", na_values='NaN') #loads the csv files       
    
    #replaces non-numeric symbols to NaN. 
    dfs = dfs.replace({'-∞': np.nan, '∞': np.nan})
    #print(dfs) #before dropping NaNs
    
    #each column taken into a separate variable
    time = dfs['Time'] #- np.min(dfs['Time']) 
    channelA = dfs['Channel A']
    channelB = dfs['Channel B'] 
    channelC = dfs['Channel C'] 
    channelD = dfs['Channel D']   
    channels = [channelA, channelB, channelC, channelD]   
    
    #printing the smallest index number which is NaN
    ind_num_A = np.where(channelA.isna())[0][0]
    ind_num_B = np.where(channelB.isna())[0][0]
    ind_num_C = np.where(channelC.isna())[0][0]
    ind_num_D = np.where(channelD.isna())[0][0]
    
    ind_num = [ind_num_A, ind_num_B, ind_num_C, ind_num_D]
    
    #dropping all rows after the first NaN is found
    rem_ind = np.amin(ind_num)  #finds the array-wise minimum
    #print('smallest index to be deleted is: ' +str(rem_ind))
    dfs = dfs.drop(dfs.index[rem_ind:])
    print(dfs) #after dropping NaNs
```

[image: Result]

The result is as I want except for the last five rows in Channel B and C, where a comma is seen instead of a point to indicate decimal. I don't know why it works everywhere else but not for a few rows. The CSV file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/84gngc8si4s2fdz/Pipe03_2.csv?dl=0).

Comment: You told `read_csv` that your decimal point is a comma.  Is it, or isn't it?

Comment: yes. In `pd.read_csv`

Comment: I don't think any of those columns are floats.  In order to have comma as a decimal point with comma as your delimiter, you have to have quotes around every value, and pandas naturally interprets those as strings.  Try printing `df["Channel B"][1]*10` and I'll bet you see a string repeated 10 times, not a floating multiply.  That's what I see.  It does change  the comma to dot if there are less than 4 digits to the left, but they're still strings.

Comment: I opened the CSV file in notepad and the values are separated with a ; and not a comma (only the decimal is a comma). So how would they be treated as a string ? Also I got `-14.650220000000001` as an answer on printing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace the non-numeric symbols `-∞` and `∞` as `NaN` already while reading, and not after the fact. If you do it after the data frame is created, then the values have been read in and it's parsed as data type `str` intead of `float`. This messes up the data types of the column.

So instead of `na_values='NaN'` do this `na_values=["-∞", "∞"]`, so the code is like this:

```
dfs = pd.read_csv(x, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1,2), decimal=",", na_values=["-∞", "∞"])

#replaces non-numeric symbols to NaN. 
# dfs = dfs.replace({'-∞': np.nan, '∞': np.nan}) # not needed anymore
```

Comment: Great ! applied and it works. How did you get the infinity symbol printed inside python? I could not do it.

Comment: So turns out this was the problem ! Not specifying non-numeric values while importing.

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. And I opened the data file in Notepad++ and copied the infinity symbol from there, but wait you had the `∞` in your original code example right? Btw maybe checkout my CSV Lint plugin https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ not sure if it would have helped with this, but might be useful.

Comment: Yeah I also copy pasted from somehwere but wanted to know if it could be directly printed.

Comment: afaik you can't type the `∞` symbol from the keyboard. In Word you can Insert > Symbol and there are some math symbols. And Windows has a `Special Characters` program, check advanced > character set Unicode and search for "infinite" or type the Unicode `221E`, but yeah not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a data type issue. Some of the values are strings so pandas will not automatically convert to float before replacing ',' with '.'.

one option is to convert each column after you read the file with something like: `df['colname'] = df['colname'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)`

Comment: Is it because the columns names are strings ? Because all others are float

Comment: No, it's because the CSV has all of those values quoted.  This answer fixes things for the sample I created to duplicate this.

Comment: Got an error `Can only use .str accessor with string values!` when applying this answer. Looks like there are no string types.