# CSV file Infinity value issue with AWS Glue job

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv, aws-glue

I have a csv file which I am reading with Pandas and trying to convert NaN and Infinity to 0.0. I have the code which I run locally and get the conversion properly such as:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df['C1'])
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.fillna(0.00)
print(df['C1'])
```

```
0    NaN
1    inf
2    NaN
Name: C1, dtype: float64
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
Name: C1, dtype: float64
```

Here, the infinity and NaN value is converted properly into 0.0 as can be seen in the output. But when I do the same in AWS Glue Python Shell job, it does not convert the infinity value to 0.0. The code and output for Glue job is as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket/test.csv')
print(df['C1'])
df = df.replace([np.Infinity, -np.Infinity], np.nan)
df = df.fillna(0.00)
print(df['C1'])
```

```
0         NaN
1    Infinity
2         NaN
Name: C1, dtype: object
0           0
1    Infinity
2           0
Name: C1, dtype: object
```

The same file is being used locally and on S3, but the issue is with infinity value. Also, locally, the data types are read as float64, but object type in Glue. Any help around this?

Comment: Looks like `inf` is a reserved word and `Infinity` is not(?), so the latter is seen as a string value. I think the trick is not to replace the `Infinity` values *after* it has already been read in, but rather *while* reading the file, so something like `pd.read_csv(.., na_values=["Infinity"]` also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68991060/1745616

Comment: If I view the file as is, Infinity is written in the values. So locally reading considers it as inf, but Glue code reads it as Infinity.

Comment: This is interesting.  I wonder if version diffs between local and the Glue runtime for Pandas and Numpy would explain it?  Either way, what about utilizing the `dtype` param to convert it during read_csv?  ie `dtype={'C1': np.float64}`

Comment: Bob, there are a lot of columns and setting this for each of them wont be possible I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it based on BdR response in the comments so here is the answer:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_path, na_values=["Infinity", "-Infinity"])
df = df.replace([np.Infinity, -np.Infinity], np.nan)
df = df.fillna(0.00)
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for sharing your findings!